# RxJs: How to implement HTTP delete with flatMap

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I've got a pretty simple use case:

- There's a `table` with some entries (each having a unique id and an index number)
- Each entry has a delete `button`
- `onclick`: call `subject.onNext` which then executes an HTTP delete call via `flatMap`
- if successful: remove the corresponding row from the table

**Rendered HTML looks (simplified) like this:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Entry1</td>
    <td><button onclick="delete.onNext({id:'a', index:0})"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Entry2</td>
    <td><button onclick="delete.onNext({id:'b', index:1})"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**delete Subject / Observable:**

```
var delete = new Rx.Subject()
    .flatMap(function(data) {
        return MyService.doHTTPDelete(data.id);
    })
    .retry() // keep the Subject alive if HTTP call fails
    .doOnError(function(err) {
        console.log("Something went wrong...", err);
    })
    .subscribe(function(???) {
        // here I need the index
    });
```

As you can see, the `MyService.doHTTPDelete` call doesn't know anything about `data.index` (and of course it is not supposed to!).

I think this is a pretty common use case. But I didn't find a solution on the web.

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flatMap` can take a second function with two parameters: the original `onNext` value, and the first function's `flatMap` result:

```
var delete = new Rx.Subject()
    .flatMap(function(data) {
        return MyService.doHTTPDelete(data.id);
    },
    function(originalData, deleteResponse) {
        // originalData is your id/index object
        // deleteResponse is the value from the doHTTPDelete
        return {
            entry: originalData,
            response: deleteResponse
        }
    })
    .subscribe(function(results) {
        // results.entry is your original onclick data
        console.log(results.entry.index);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some workaround, that's quite simple. But I don't know if there are any possible side effects or unwanted behavior:

```
var delete = new Rx.Subject()
    .flatMap(function(data) {
        return MyService.doHTTPDelete(data.id)
                .map(function() { return data; });
    })
    ....;
```